# Keeping UI up to date with service

Tags: android-service, android, android-networking

I've implemented a IntentService that fetchs data from my servers and returns result as JSON through ResultReceiver that's given to the service via intent.

My problem is keeping UI up to date with the services state, for example logging in to my server happens through this service, if I wanted to tell the user that the program is working on the logging in I'd like to show a progress dialog, but what happens when someone calls while the service is still fetching data, user rotates phone or changes activity?

I don't want to leave user looking at screen that has login button and when the login is done it just shows toast indicating the state, I want keep the user notified about the current state.

How can I handle the progress dialog without creating hundreds of lines of duplicate code when accessing my service?

Currently on my LoginActivity after user wants to login it calls login function in my ApiAccessor which handles communicating with service and registers a callback when the result is back in such way:

```
ProgressDialog dialog;


dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait..", "Logging in..");
accessor.login(usernameField.getText().toString(), passwordField.getText().toString(), new ApiCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(ApiResponse response) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

but now I have to handle dismissing and respawning dialog in onPause, onResume and onDestroy too, and I have to do this in every activity!

What is the common way of keeping UI up to date with the services state or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll want to read on the BIND part of the whole Service guides and documentation.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

After an activity is bound to a service, the activity can call up any methods on it, so you can:

- Create an interface
- Create method on the service such as `setOnSomethingHappenListener(MyInterface listener)`
- implement the interface on the activity
- from the activity call `myService.setOnSomethingHappenListener(this);`
- from the service, if listener not null, you call the methods from the interface (passing those events to whichever activity is attached to it)
- don't forget to override `onUnbind` to null the listener.

Comment: That doesn't really change the current situation, right? I'd still have to have lost of duplicate code in order to handle such as showing progress dialog correctly? This would probably even make thing more complicated, because IntentService already does a lot of work to me, and isn't it supposed to only do one task and return?

Comment: `What is the common way of keeping UI up to date with the services state or so?` that's the binder, the service will be just one (nothing duplicate) and the activities just binds to running services (maybe shouldn't be IntentService, would have to analyse more details). Regarding implementing it on all activities, you can make the listener a separate object from the activity but initialised with it. You could make an abstract base activity that does the code and have the others extend it. There are ways! But it needs a proper analyse of the whole system to define which way to do.

Comment: Thanks, had a problem with my mindset about binding to services, solved my problem. :)